# How to calculate Vol(M), where M is a ellipictal cone?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, volume, spherical-coordinates, spheres

How can I calculate the Volume of $M = \left\{ (x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3: 0\le z \le \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}}\ \mathrm{and}\ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} \le \sqrt{\frac{x}{a}} \right\}$ for $a,b >0$.

Aparently $M$ describes a half of some kind of elliptical cone.

1) I tried to start with generalized cylindrical coordinates:
$\Phi(r, \phi, z) = \begin{pmatrix}ar \cos\phi\\br \sin\phi\\z\end{pmatrix}$

This gives $M=\left\{(r,\phi,z)\in \mathbb R^3: 0 \le z \le r\ \ \mathrm{and}\ r^2 \le \sqrt{r \cos\phi}\right\}$.

$r^2 \le \sqrt{r \cos\phi}$ means $\phi\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and $0 < r  \le 1$.

The next step is to calculate a new surface element?

2) I also tried to do it in cartesian coords by resolving the y-radius of the Ellipse:
$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} \le \sqrt{\frac{x}{a}} \Leftrightarrow y^2 \le \left[\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^{1/2} - \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2 \right] b^2$.
If I plot this function I can see the the right right is positive for $x\in[0,a]$ and hence $\left|y\right| \le \pm ab^2$.

Then I could calc
$Vol(M) = \int_M dV = \int_{-ab^2}^{+ab^2} dy \int_0^a dx \int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}}} dz$.

Question: Is this correct? Is there a easier or more elegant way to this? Is there an easy way to visualize M without plotting it on a computer?

Thanks!

EDIT: Corrected description: Before I asked for a spheroid.

Comment: $z=r$ is a cone. $0\leq z\leq r$ is the space between the cone and a flat plane touching its vertex. $0\leq r\leq1$ is a solid cylinder. The combination $0\leq z\leq r\leq1$ is the intersection of these two regions, which is not a spheroid.

Comment: An easy way to find its volume is to subtract the volume of the solid cone $r\leq z\leq1$ from that of the solid cylinder $r\leq1,\;0\leq z\leq1$. (Then cut this in half.)

Comment: z = r is only valid in my defined transform coordinate system. In a cartesian coord system I don't have a real cone as long as $a \ne b$ or am I wrong?

Comment: It's an elliptical cone. The coordinate system is simply stretched, so the volume scales by $ab$.

Comment: The volume factor should be:

$\mathrm{det}\left|\begin{pmatrix}a\cos\phi & -ar\sin\phi & 0\\b\sin\phi&br\cos\phi&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\right| = abr |\cos\phi|$

This yields:

$\mathrm{Vol}(M) = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^1 \int_0^r abr |\cos\phi| \ dz \ dr \ d\phi = \frac{ab\pi}{6}$.

Is that correct?

Comment: No, I'm getting $(2/3)\pi ab$. Otherwise it looks correct. And the absolute value is unnecessary because $\cos\phi>0$ for $-\pi/2<\phi<\pi/2$.

Comment: Wait, where did the $\cos\phi$ come from? The determinant is just $abr$.

Comment: Oh, it should be obviously $\cos^2(\phi)$, when calculating the determinant. Then it correctly yields $\frac{ab\pi}{6}$. :)

Comment: ...$(2/3)\pi ab$ is for the whole (cylinder minus cone); I forgot to half it to $(1/3)\pi ab$. This is the same as your integral without the $\cos\phi$.

Comment: The volume of a standard catersian cone is $\frac{r^2\pi h}{3}$. Here $h = 1$ and $r = ab$ and since it's only half cone, it needs to be a half of it, ie $\frac{ab\pi}{6}$. Hence I am confused about your result and I cannot follow you calculation. Have you done the calculation with $\cos(\phi)^2$?

Comment: We're not finding the volume of a cone. We're finding the volume of the region between a cone and a plane, which is a cylinder minus a cone.

Comment: For the determinant, $(a\cos\phi)(br\cos\phi)-(b\sin\phi)(-ar\sin\phi)=abr(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi)=abr$.

Comment: (The comments don't update immediately after edits...)

Comment: You are absolutely right about the determinant and it's good to see that we come to the same solutions.

I have drawn a sketch on my paper and could finally follow your drain of thoughts. I will post a full solution with all explanations and a drawing later, when I find some more time. Until then, thank you very much!

Comment: If you find your solution, don't edit the question; post it as an answer.